# how to update already running selenium RC test from a Java client?

Tags: java, selenium-rc, embedded-jetty

How to approach the following scenario?

Say a  test is already running in selenium rc node on a remote server using RemoteWebDriver.

The test encounters a missing element (slightest xpath change across different pages).

User provides the correct xpath for that element (this part is done in the Java application running on the user's computer) and selenium test searches for the element again and continues with rest of the test.

First thing that comes to mind is that Selenium server is using Jetty server. How would I communicate between by client java application and this server? can Jetty be ignored and somehow make the client communicate directly with the running selenium test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the element can not be located by a given xpath the webdriver will throw an exception which will bubble back to where you are running your test. As long as you catch this exception you will have the chance to check different xpaths.

Comment: but how do I "listen" for a new xpath?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to pass the new xpaths from another application. That's another issue of IPC between your applications and is not related to Selenium.

Comment: yes, how to make selenium test wait and pause the remote browser, when NoSuchElementException is raised, listen to a port until new string is sent by the client....I have a feeling this is not possible without recompiling the test?

Comment: It will just keep waiting till you do driver.quit() or something. You can take your time sending requests. The driver will keep a heartbeat with the webdriver in your test.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are looking for , halt the execution in the browser and continue that execution from where ever you want (from previous statement ), instead of the browser responding back to selenium RC  and to client program.

-- you want to completely stop the browser response to the request made by the selenium RC

if this is correct can you please confirm, may be i can help you.

Comment: ok kim this could only be done with javascript i think but i will get back to you with specific answer this week end. sorry bit busy with the other things now..